# Merge unequal length data.frames by id in R

Tags: r

Sample data

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7,7),dna=c(232,424,5345,45345,45,345,4543,345345,4545))

y <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7,7),year=c(2001,2002,2003,2005,2006,2000,2001,2002,2003))
```

Merge doesn't give good solution `merge(x,y,by="id")`, which gives duplicates.

Now for the above sample data simple cbind works `cbind(x,y)` and this is what I'm after, just paring the `year` with corresponding `id`.

Problem arrises when the two data.frames do not match! So that the data.frame containing variable `year` is shorter. Someting like this:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7,7),dna=c(232,424,5345,45345,45,345,4543,345345,4545))

y <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7),year=c(2001,2002,2003,2005,2006,2000,2001,2002))
```

So I need paring the two data.frames and the corresponding unmatched rows of data.frame `x` could be NA's so that I would remove that row.

Desired output for the shorter sample data:

```
     id year dna
  1  1 2001 232
  2  1 2002 424
  3  1 2003 5345
  4  2 2005 45345
  5  2 2006 45
  6  7 2000 345
  7  7 2001 4543
  8  7 2002 345345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a record number to each id so you can work with `merge`:

```
x <- transform(x, rec = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))
y <- transform(y, rec = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))

merge(x, y, c("id", "rec"))
#   id rec    dna year
# 1  1   1    232 2001
# 2  1   2    424 2002
# 3  1   3   5345 2003
# 4  2   1  45345 2005
# 5  2   2     45 2006
# 6  7   1    345 2000
# 7  7   2   4543 2001
# 8  7   3 345345 2002
```